# Spotify API node

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify

Im not entirely sure why my cmd keeps returning `undefined` when I type in `console.log(data2.body.artists.name);`.

But when I keep it at `console.log(data2.body.artists);` it will display [the screen shot I included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eehz.jpg).

Anyone know whats going wrong here? I just want the artist name to appear.

```
spotifyApi.getArtistRelatedArtists('137W8MRPWKqSmrBGDBFSop')
  .then(function(data2) {
    console.log('Top Related Artists:')
    console.log(data2.body.artists.name);
  }, function(err) {
    done(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data2.body.artists` is an array of objects. So you need to get a name of the artist at some index. For example the first artists name:

```
data2.body.artists[0].name
```